# Не срабатывает событие OnChange

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте всем!

Такая проблема при переключении языка: переключается только последний в списке, не могу понять, в чем проблема.

```
<form name="Lang_form" method="post" action="index.php">
     <select onChange="lang_form()" name="new_language">
         {section name=i loop=$lang_list}     
         <option value="{$smarty.section.i.index}">{$lang_list[i]->description}</option>
        {/section}
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: А можно посмотреть сгенерированный код и саму функцию? Кстати, попробуйте сделать так: onСhange="alert('['+this.value+']')"

Answer (score 1):

Было бы, конечно, неплохо посмотреть скомпилированный шаблон. Проверьте значения value у option'ов - соответствуют ли они тому, чего Вы ожидаете? Вариант предложенный ling'ом для этого подойдет (alert). Ну и, конечно, функцию lang_form() в студию!

С уважением,

Comment: вот функция




{literal}
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  function lang_form(){
   document.Lang_form.submit();
  }
 </script>
{/literal}

Comment: а это пхп код



if (isset($_POST["new_language"]))
{
$_SESSION["current_language"] = $_POST["new_language"];
}

if (!isset($_SESSION["current_language"]) ||
$_SESSION["current_language"] < 0 || $_SESSION["current_language"] > count($lang_list))
$_SESSION["current_language"] = 0; 

if (isset($lang_list[$_SESSION["current_language"]]) && file_exists("./languages/".$lang_list[$_SESSION["current_language"]]->filename))
include("./languages/".$lang_list[$_SESSION["current_language"]]->filename);
else
{
die("<font color=red><b>ERROR: Couldn't find language file!</b></font>");
}

Comment: А можно увидеть html-код?

Comment: А содержимое $lang_list каково? И что конкретно Вы имеете в виду, говоря что "переключается только последний в списке" - что можно выбрать только этот язык? или что он единственный доступный? или что никакие другие не включаются (хотя в списке есть?). Выдаются ли какие-либо ошибки в еррор логе php?... Пока что ситуация не совсем ясна, ошибок в Вашем коде (php) вроде нету... Единственное, что могу предложить на данный момент - проверьте код инициализации шаблона... Вы не забыли выполнить $smarty->assign('lang_list',$lang_list);(или что-то подобное, если это нужно, конечно)

Comment: я имею ввиду что в списке 2 языка русский и английский, русский первый второй английский. Выбирая в списке английский срабатывает английский, выбирая русский он даже не кликается т.е. обратно на русский не переключается. html код вверху, а исходник вот
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function lang_form(){
document.Lang_form.submit();
}
</script>
<form name="Lang_form" method="post" action="index.php">
<select onChange="lang_form()" name="new_language">
<option value="0">Русский</option>
<option value="1">English</option>
</select>
</form> как сделать чтобы код было видно

Comment: Ну конечно. Изначально значение select = 0. Выбирая option со значением 0 вы не меняете значения select - вот ничего и не происходит. Попробуйте сначала вставить &lt;option value="">-- Выберите язык --&lt;/option> , а потом уже - список языков.

Comment: кажется понял. По видимому, у Вас Русский - значение по умолчанию. Поэтому событие OnChange при клике на русский НЕ СРАБАТЫВАЕТ. Измените код шаблона так, чтобы при выбранном английском языке он устанавливал свойство selected опции Английского языка. Чтобы для английского при выбранном английском генерировался код:

[option value="1" selected="selected" ]English[/option]

Или же просто вставьте в шаблон ПЕРЕД НАЧАЛОМ section строку [option value="-1"]_nbsp;[/option] (замените [] на <>, а _ на &)

Comment: насчет "видимости" кода. В комментариях - по-видимому - никак. Я менял <> на []... Ну да это уже не важно. Все что надо мы увидели.